# Android - How to use SharedPreferences in non-Activity class?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How do you use SharedPreferences in a non-Activity class? I tried making a generic Preferences utility class and importing `android.content.Context` but Eclipse still wouldn't let me use `getSharedPreferences()`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

SharedPreferences are related to context.
You can only reference it through a context.

You can simply pass context as a parameter to your class.
For example in the constructor.

In your activity do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

Comment: Aha! That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the simple and clear answer. Now I can access it using `context.getSharedPreferences();`.

Comment: error was MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: My activity does not allow a `this` in my other class constructor (the class with the `SharedPreferences`).

Comment: @Prasad Use 0. It's the same thing.

Comment: We can use static method http://www.freakyjolly.com/shared-preference-context-error-android/

Answer (score 51):

The solution i found to this was:

1-In an MainActivity class (i.e always launched before getting any context in project) create a static variable for the context:

```java
public static Context contextOfApplication;
```

2-In an important method of this class (Such as onCreate, the constructor, etc) initialize this variable using the getApplicationContext method:

```java
public void onCreate() {
    contextOfApplication = getApplicationContext();
}
```

3-In the same class Create a "getter" method for this variable (it must also be static):

```java
public static Context getContextOfApplication(){
    return contextOfApplication;
}
```

4-In the non-activity class get the context by calling the created method statically:

```java
Context applicationContext = MyActivityClass.getContextOfApplication();
```

5-Use the PreferenceManager Class to get the SharedPreferences variable:

```java
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a useful workaround, I'd suggest to use contextOfApplication as a private field

Comment: You can also use        
              applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(pref_name, 
             MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: This is such a hacky solution and an anti-pattern, exposing a public static Context variable in the Activity.

But if you decide to go this way worth noting that since the member `public static Context contextOfApplication;` is public and static, you wouldn't need the `getContextOfApplication()` method to access that.

In step 4 you can just do `MyActivityClass.contextOfApplication` and it would work.

Answer (score 4):

In **Kotlin**, there's a nice & simple wrapper-based solution – just **copy & paste** the code into a new `AppPreferences.kt` file and **follow the 4 TODO steps** outlined in the code:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.core.content.edit

object AppPreferences {
    private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null

    // TODO step 1: call `AppPreferences.setup(applicationContext)` in your MainActivity's `onCreate` method
    fun setup(context: Context) {
        // TODO step 2: set your app name here
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("<YOUR_APP_NAME>.sharedprefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    // TODO step 4: replace these example attributes with your stored values
    var heightInCentimeters: Int?
        get() = Key.HEIGHT.getInt()
        set(value) = Key.HEIGHT.setInt(value)

    var birthdayInMilliseconds: Long?
        get() = Key.BIRTHDAY.getLong()
        set(value) = Key.BIRTHDAY.setLong(value)

    private enum class Key {
        HEIGHT, BIRTHDAY; // TODO step 3: replace these cases with your stored values keys

        fun getBoolean(): Boolean? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getBoolean(name, false) else null
        fun getFloat(): Float? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getFloat(name, 0f) else null
        fun getInt(): Int? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getInt(name, 0) else null
        fun getLong(): Long? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getLong(name, 0) else null
        fun getString(): String? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getString(name, "") else null

        fun setBoolean(value: Boolean?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putBoolean(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setFloat(value: Float?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putFloat(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setInt(value: Int?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putInt(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setLong(value: Long?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putLong(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setString(value: String?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putString(name, value) } } ?: remove()

        fun remove() = sharedPreferences!!.edit { remove(name) }
    }
}
```

Now from anywhere within your app you can **get a value** like this:

```
val heightInCentimeters: Int? = AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters
val heightOrDefault: Int = AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters ?: 170
```

**Setting a value** to the `SharedPreferences` is just as easy:

```
AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters = 160 // sets a new value
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [default preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) with an Application context. A context is similar to the environment an application runs in on linux or windows (e.g. environment variables like PATH windowing style or console size).  Each Activity and Service has its own Context too for example screen orientation, theme, and label, etc. but for your application you don't want the context of the Activity, you want something global to the app, this is where [context.getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) is useful. This the same throughout the app and will always give you the same default preferences.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I tried `SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);` no matter where you are in the code it requires a context to use the Preferences.

Comment: @DanS - And where do you expect him to get the applicationContext from when he is having an issue just getting the context ?

Comment: @Bamerza As I said a `Context` is required and other answers show how to store a `Context` in a static fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Using a static method to use **SharedPreference** *without Context Object* explained [**here**](http://www.freakyjolly.com/shared-preference-context-error-android/)

In **MainActivity** before **OnCreate**

```
public static SharedPreferences preferences;
```

In **OnCreate** method add

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences( getPackageName() + "_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Create a **PreferenceHelper** Class with static methods of **Getters** and **Setters**

```
public class PreferenceHelper {

final public static String KEY_DEMO_NAME = "Demo Name";
public static void setName(String value) {
    MainActivity.preferences.edit().putString(KEY_DEMO_NAME, value ).commit();
}
public static String getName() {
    return MainActivity.preferences.getString(KEY_DEMO_NAME,"");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In main activity add: u will get global static shared preferences object

```
 companion object {    
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 sharedPreferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
        SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code to a new class.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
   * Created by Atiar Talukdar on 6/5/2017.
*/

public class TemporaryStorageSharedPreference {
protected final static int DEFAULT = 0;
int temp = 0;

public int readSharedPreference(Context context, String spName,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(spName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return temp = sharedPreferences.getInt(key,DEFAULT);
}

public void writeSharedPreference(Context context,String ammount,String spName,String key ){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(spName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, DEFAULT);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Kotlin you can do this:

```
val myClass = MyClass(this)
```

Now this is how you can get context in class

```
class MyClass(context: Context) {

    val context: Context = context

}
```

Now to get Shared Preferences with context you can do this:

```
context.getSharedPreferences(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a private attribute in your class. In my case, I have a BaseAdapter class:

```
private final Context ctx;
private final Vector<Acto> actos;

public ActoAdaptador(Context ctx, Vector<Acto> as) {
    super();
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.actos = as;
}
```

Then, when to use the SharedPreferences:

```
ctx.getSharedPreferences("com.joninazio.euskofest.UsingPreferences_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

That way works for me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

**create SharedPreferences class**

```
 /**
     * @param mContext
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public static void savePreferences(Context mContext, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param keyValue
     * @return
     */
    public static String getPreferences(Context context, String keyValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(keyValue, "");
    }

    /**
     * @param mContext
     */
    public static void removeAllSharedPreferences(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear().apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the `context` from activity.

```
if (context != null) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For **Kotlin** and for **default** preference file, you can use the following code:

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Comment: The post was asking for non-activity class